# count the number of film instances

Tags: c++, qt4

Here is my implementation

Film.h    //header

```
#ifndef FILM_H
#define FILM_H
#include <QString>

class Film {
  protected:
    QString title;
    double dailyRate;
  public:
    Film(QString ti,double dr);
    virtual double calculateRental(int num)const;
};

#endif // FILM_H
```

Film.cpp

```
#include "film.h"
#include <QString>

Film::Film(QString ti,double dr){
  title=ti;
  dailyRate=dr;
 }

 double Film::calculateRental(int num)const {
 return dailyRate*num;
}
```

main.cpp

```
 #include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
 #include <QtCore/QTextStream>
 #include  "film.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
 QTextStream cout(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
 Film f("Top Gun", 10.00); //create an instance of a film
 cout <<f.calculateRental(2);
 return a.exec();

}
```

how do I count the number of Film instances created? I know is something like that:

```
static int numOfFilms;
numOfFilms++;
```

how do I use the code?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Any compiler errors, or runtime results that you weren't expecting?

Comment: really, you want `title` and `dailyRate` be `const` members (whence they need initialisation in the ctor via `: title(ti), dailyRate(dr) {}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If you replace `Class` with `class`, and `QString` has a conversion constructor from `const char*`, then yes.

Comment: what if the conversion constructor remains const?

Comment: @AnnitaZirki a constructor can't be `const`.

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj that's the one.